# Soft-delete on has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm, associations

What is the easiest way to implement **soft-deletes on has_many through** association?

What I want is something like this:

```
class Company > ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :staffings
  has_many :users, through: :staffings, conditions: {staffings: {active: true}}
end
```

I want to use `Company#users` the following way:

- the `Company#users` should be a normal association so that it **works with forms** and doesn't break existing contract.
- when adding a **user** to the company, a new `Staffing` with `active: true` is **created**.
- when **removing** a user from a company, the existing `Staffing` is updated `active: false` (currently it **just gets deleted**).
- when adding a **previously removed user** to the company (so that `Staffing#active == false`) the `Staffing` is updated to `active: true`.

I thought about overriding the `Company#users=` method, but it really isn't good enough since there are other ways of updating the associations.

So the question is: **how to achieve the explained behaviour on the `Company#users` association?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`has_many :through` associations are really just syntactic sugar. When you need to do heavy lifting, I would suggest splitting up the logic and providing the appropriate methods and scopes. Understanding how to override [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) is useful for this sort of thing also.

This will get you started with soft deletes on `User` and creating `Staffings` after a `User`

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :staffings
  has_many :users, through: :staffings, conditions: ['staffings.active = ?', true]
end

class Staffing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_one :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staffing

  # after callback fires, create a staffing
  after_create {|user| user.create_staffing(active: true)}

  # override the destroy method since you 
  # don't actually want to destroy the User
  def destroy
    run_callbacks :delete do
      self.staffing.active = false if self.staffing
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm well aware of the callbacks and all that. I don't think you've read the question. How can I use `Company#users` the way I described?

Comment: Which of your four use cases does my answer not provide a solution to? You can leave the `Company` definition as you had it, and add the `after_create` callback and the overridden `destroy` method and all the functionality you mentioned should be accounted for.  Perhaps some clarification of how you intend to use `Company#users` would be helpful, as you actually didn't explain how you plan to use  `Company#users` just that there were four contracts it needed to meet.

Comment: I've updated the question a bit. Take time to read it please.